# A delegating constructor cannot have other mem-initializers - error

Tags: c++, constructor, delegates

I'm trying to do something like in the code below. I'm getting error like in the question title from VS. Can anybody tells me what's wrong?

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A(int x = 15)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int a,b,c;


    B(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }

    B(int a, int b, int c, int x) : A(x), /*here is error*/B(a,b,c)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Please always post compiler error messages *verbatim*. Don't tell us what you *think* they say, or otherwise paraphrase them. Just post the raw text you got. Please. Also don't just post code *snippets*. Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

In your 4-parameter constructor for `B`, you can't construct the base class `A`, then delegate to another constructor.  That other constructor would also construct `A`, potentially causing all kinds of havoc.

You'll either need to duplicate the initialization of `B`'s members, put them in a helper function, or delegate from the 3-parameter function to the 4-parameter function (providing the proper value for the 4th parameter which is passed to the constructor for `A`).

```
B(int a, int b, int c): B(a, b, c, 15)
{
}
```